# Full outer join on four tables in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to conduct a full outer join on four tables in Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

The tables look like the following:

Table1

```
SubjectID   DATE         
001         01/11/2014   
001         02/11/2013   
002         02/10/2015   
003         08/12/2013   
002         01/31/2012   
003         07/19/2016
```

Table 2

```
SubjectID   DATE         
006         05/11/2012   
006         03/11/2013   
008         09/10/2018   
008         11/12/2014   
010         01/12/2011   
010         04/27/2017
```

Table 3

```
SubjectID   DATE         
012         06/11/2012   
012         04/11/2010   
014         08/10/2011   
014         07/12/2017   
015         01/12/2013   
015         05/27/2018
```

Table 4

```
SubjectID          
021            
021           
022            
022            
035            
035
```

I'd like to create a table that contains all of the subjects and dates. Also, I want to make sure all duplicate entries would be removed (I think I can do this with the DISTINCT keyword).

Comment: Yes I think you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can use `full outer join`, I would recommend `union` :

```
select subjectid, date from table1 union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select subjectid, date from table2 union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select subjectid, date from table3 union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select subjectid, date from table4
```